# Empty View in Expandable List Adapter

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list that I am creating using a custom adapter class extending `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. Is there a way for me to add an empty view child under each of the groups in my expandable list when there are no items in that group?

**EDIT:**
I tried to use `mExpList.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty_child));` but it did not work. `R.id.empty_child` is in the same xml right below the expandable list view.

Comment: please add more code if you still need an answer. This is not enough to find your problem

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the **getChildView()** method, you can determine if that group has any children. If there aren't any, you can return an Empty View.

At the same time, you will need to adjust the other related methods like,
**getChildrenCount()**, **getChild()** etc.

Comment: This is what I thought of too! But `getChildView()` doesn't even get called if the group is empty. I just tried it again with a log statement at the start of `getChildView()` and toggled the empty group on my phone. The logs didn't get printed out.

Comment: You have to adjust the getChildrenCount() to return 1 instead of 0 for the groups that are empty.

Comment: Ah! that sounds like it will work! Let me try and get back to you.